# Por que seria interessante adicionar ou remover elemento HTML do DOM?

Tags: html, angular, dom

Estou iniciando meus estudos em Angular 7 e em uma aula sobre Structural Directives, aprendi que eu posso adicionar ou remover elementos `HTML` do `DOM`.

Entendi que *existem 3 principais*, o `ngIf`, o `ngSwitch` e o `ngFor`.

O `ngIf` e o `ngSwitch` são usados para rederizar condicionalmente os elementos `HTML`.
O `ngFor` é utilizado para renderizar uma lista de elementos `HTML`.

Usando o `ngIf`, tenho um exemplo:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  //templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  template: `

    <h2 *ngIf="true">
        Marcielli
    </h2>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

*OBS: Para propósito de estudo, estou usando no mesmo arquivo.*

Quando `ngIf` está setado para `true`, na tela fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando está setado para `false`, fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**A pergunta é: Em qual situação real eu usaria isso? Por qual motivo, por exemplo, eu iria querer remover um elemento do DOM?**

Comment: em elementos dinâmicos, pensa em um controle de estoque aonde pode ser controlado por und. ou peso pela característica do item vc pode aplicar a dinamicidade caso seja do tipo und, apresenta tal controle ou ate mesmo tal input, ou caso seja peso tal controle ou tal input

Answer (score 3):

> A pergunta é: Em qual situação real eu usaria isso? Por qual motivo, por exemplo, eu iria querer remover um elemento do DOM?

Na pratica existe varios exemplos, vou citar dois mais usados no meu dia-a-dia:

1. Nível de acesso, exibe determinadas parte do html de acordo com o nível de permissão do usuário.
2. Formulário, adicionar novo campo, remover ou exibir campos em progresso (quando o critério for atigido exibe o próximo item).

A ideia básica seria o usuário final poder controlar o formulario via html.
O mesmo tambem poderia ser feito com apenas um `hide()` (ocultar a via css), mas isso não teria a camada de segurança que evita que o usuario manipule todos os dados via console.